# Quickbooks Queuing

Tags: php, mysql, api, quickbooks

Currently i have a customer form which inserts data into multiple tables.
I am integrating with QuickBooks PHP-API (Consolibyte).

When the data is inserted following is the queuing method that proceeds after insertion in a table.

```
$Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $id);
```

where $id is the last_insert_id() in a table.

Since there are entries happening to multiple tables, how do i update Customer records in Quickbooks by fetching data from multiple table since each table will return its own last insert id.

Comment: Can you clarify what your multiple tables are?  You have multiple tables, and then each have customers in them? e.g. `customers_1`, `customers_2`, etc.?  What is the purpose of the multiple tables?

Comment: the details of Customer_1 are in multiple tables. eg. customer_1 (name,email) in table1 whereas same customer_1(tel,address,..other details) in table2.

Comment: OK... so are those tables related to each other somehow? By some common shared key value?

Comment: yes there is a foreign key in table2 named 'customer_id'. so do you mean i can write a join and fetch all the data from both tables for the recent customer added ?

Comment: Yes. So when you queue stuff up, queue it up by the common `customer_id` field. That's your primary key to get all the data from all the tables, so use that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since there are entries happening to multiple tables`

Presumably, you have a common `customer_id` field or something that is shared across all tables.

Use that `customer_id` value.

> how do i update Customer records in Quickbooks by fetching data from multiple table

SQL supports something called `JOIN`s which are specifically meant to allow you to "smush" two related tables together and get all the data related to your specific customer from all of the related tables.

Use a `JOIN`. Get all the data from the tables.

Build your qbXML request from that.